# Adding count columns based on criteria within sub query

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Hoping I can articulate this correctly. I have 3 tables within a Risk & Control database.

Table 1 contains details on all Risks and their likelihood of occurrence. Risk ID is a unique value :

```
Risk ID |Risk Desc |Impact  | Likelihood
4363    | XXX      | High   | Likely
2357    | XXX      | Low    | Unlikely
7629    | XXX      | Medium | Unlikely
1929    | XXX      | Low    | Likely
```

Table 2 contains details on all Controls, and a rating on their effectiveness. Control ID is a unique value :

```
Control ID | Control Rating 
4566       | Effective
1431       | Not Effective
6724       | Effective
3415       | Effective
```

Table 3 contains a mapping of Risks with their linked controls in a 'many to many relationship' ie a risk can link to multiple controls and vice-versa.

```
Risk ID  | Control |
4363     | 4566    |
4363     | 1431    |
2357     | 4566    |
7629     | 6724    |
```

I am trying to create a view of all risk and an aggregated view of their control effectiveness, with 3 count columns. One that counts the total number of linked controls, one that counts the total number of EFFECTIVE controls and one that counts the total number of NOT EFFECTIVE controls.

The output would look like this :

```
Risk ID |Risk Desc |Impact  | Likelihood | Controls | Effective | Not Effective 
4363    | XXX      | High   | Likely     | 2        | 1         | 1
2357    | XXX      | Low    | Unlikely   | 1        | 1         | 0
7629    | XXX      | Medium | Unlikely   | 1        | 1         | 0
1929    | XXX      | Low    | Likely     | 1        | 0         | 1
```

I have managed to get the first part, however not sure how I add the other counts?

```
SELECT Table_1.RISK_ID,
       Table_1.RISK_DESC,
       Table_1.Impact,       
       Table_1.Likelihood,
COUNT(TABLE_2.CONTROL_ID) AS Total_Controls
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN Table_2
ON Table_1.RISK_ID       = Table_2.RISK_ID
GROUP BY Table_1.RISK_ID,
         Table_1.RISK_DESC,
         Table_1.Impact,       
         Table_1.Likelihood
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this is correct. In your sample tables you have no risk id in table two but your example shows you joining table one and table two on risk_id? So i'll just write this assuming your sample tables are correct.

```
    SELECT Table_1.RISK_ID,
       Table_1.RISK_DESC,
       Table_1.Impact,       
       Table_1.Likelihood,
COUNT(TABLE_2.CONTROL_ID) AS Total_Controls,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONTROL_RATING IN ('Effective') THEN 'x' END) as effective,
COUNT(CASE WHEN CONTROL_RATING IN ('Not Effective') THEN 'x' END) as not_effective
FROM Table_1
INNER JOIN Table_3 
ON Table_3.Risk_ID = Table_1.Risk_ID
INNER JOIN Table_2
ON Table_2.CONTROL_ID       = Table_3.CONTROL
GROUP BY Table_1.RISK_ID,
         Table_1.RISK_DESC,
         Table_1.Impact,       
         Table_1.Likelihood
```

Sum will also work in this, but you wanted COUNT()

Comment: Thanks K.Layton - my mistake when giving the sample table. Your solution has worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You could use simple math and aggregation for your "effective" and "not effective" columns. Pseudo Code:

Controls = COUNT(*)

Effective = SUM(CASE WHEN Control_Rating="Effective" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Not Effective = SUM(CASE WHEN Control_Rating="Not Effective" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)